# HttpWebRequest doesn't work after server IP changed while I use domain

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ip, httpwebrequest

Following code worked file until server IP changed. I use domain in URL.

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://example.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic ......");

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
```

Error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS channel.

But postman does it.

Comment: Do you have Tls settings on the ServicePointManager? Make sure they include the protocols needed by the server. If it is a new server expect Tls13 to be required, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel or you have a cipher mismatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766145/system-net-webexception-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-sec

Comment: Not only the IP changed, the server's TLS settings changed.

Comment: tried ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;still got no luck

Comment: tried add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; on top but got error "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Comment: Don't you have Tls13? What framework version are you on? What is your OS?

Comment: Are you sure all certificates that come back from that server are trusted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620230/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with-auth ?

Comment: When I add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288; on top, error changed to "An unexpected error occurred on a receive". Is that mean Tls is Tls13?

Comment: My computer's framework is 4.5, windows 10. Don't know server information